# Como mostrar as postagens deste ano no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Olá gostaria de saber como posso alterar o código abaixo, para que ele só mostre as postagens do ano em que estamos. De forma que quando chegar o próximo ano só mostre as postagens do ano referente. Mantendo no caso as configurações do `meta_key` e `meta_value`, por que necessito que os itens que sejam mostrados possuam os dados contidos nesses dois campos.

```
<?php

if(get_option('dt_me_random_order2') =='true') {
    $rand = 'rand';
} else {
    $rand = '';
} 

// Desativa o modo de Slide Show da Index

if(get_option('dt_me_ativar_slider2') =='true') {
// Se não tiver ativado a ordem e modo slide apartece essas variavies que seram adicionadas nas verificações abaixo
    $ativarSlide = 'id="dt-episodes2"';
    $setasSlide = '<div class="nav_items_module">
  <a class="btn prevmg"><i class="icon-caret-left"></i></a>
  <a class="btn nextmg"><i class="icon-caret-right"></i></a>
</div>';
}
else {
// Se não tiver ativado a ordem e modo slide apartece essas variavies que seram adicionadas nas verificações abaixo
    $ativarSlide = '';
}
// Aplica as configurações no laço de repetição
    query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => array('episodes'),
    'showposts' => get_option('dt_me_number_items2','20'),
    'meta_key' => 'colocar_este_episodio_na_home',
    'meta_value' => 'Sim',
    'orderby' => $rand,
    'order' => 'desc'
));
?>
<header>
<h2><?php echo get_option('dt_me_title2','Mega Lançamentos'); ?></h2>
<?php if(get_option('dt_me_autoplay_slider2') <> 'true') { echo $setasSlide; } else { } ?>
<span><?php if($url = get_option('dt_episodes_slug','episodes')) { if(get_option('dt_me_todos_lancamentos') =='true') { ?><a href="<?php echo site_url().'/mega_lancamentos/'; ?>" class="see-all"><?php _d('Ver Mega Lançamentos'); ?> - Total (<?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?>)</a><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ) .'/'. $url .'/'; ?>" class="see-all"><?php _d('Ver Todos os Lançamentos'); ?> - Total (<?php echo doo_total_count('episodes'); ?>)</a><?php } else { ?><a href="<?php echo site_url().'/mega_lancamentos/'; ?>" class="see-all"><?php _d('Ver Mega Lançamentos'); ?> - Total (<?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?>)</a><? } } ?></span>
</header>
<div id="epiloadmg" class="load_modules"><?php _d('Loading..');?></div>
<div <?php echo $ativarSlide; ?> class="animation-2 items">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('inc/parts/item_ep'); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php if(get_option('dt_me_ativar_slider2') <> 'true') { ?><header><span id="vertudobaixo"><span><?php if($url = get_option('dt_episodes_slug','episodes')) { if(get_option('dt_me_todos_lancamentos') =='true') { ?><a href="<?php echo site_url().'/mega_lancamentos/'; ?>" class="see-all"><?php _d('Ver Mega Lançamentos'); ?> - Total (<?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?>)</a><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ) .'/'. $url .'/'; ?>" class="see-all"><?php _d('Ver Todos os Lançamentos'); ?> - Total (<?php echo doo_total_count('episodes'); ?>)</a><?php } else { ?><a href="<?php echo site_url().'/mega_lancamentos/'; ?>" class="see-all"><?php _d('Ver Mega Lançamentos'); ?> - Total (<?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?>)</a><? } } ?></span></span></header><? } else { }

// Reseta os dados da query do while
wp_reset_query();  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai conseguir isso seguindo o exemplo abaixo:

```
// O parâmetro "year" vai trazer somente posts do ano informado.
query_posts( array(
    'post_type'  => array('episodes'),
    'showposts'  => get_option('dt_me_number_items2','20'),
    'meta_key'   => 'colocar_este_episodio_na_home',
    'meta_value' => 'Sim',
    'orderby'    => $rand,
    'order'      => 'desc',
    'year'       => date( 'Y' ) // A função date com o parâmetro Y retorna o ano atual.
));
```